# What are the options of joining the external library in Android using Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle

For example: there is a project on GitHub https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh, it uses Gradle, so you can add to a project using:

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh: library: +'
```

And there is a project https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss, where Gradle is not used.
What are the ways to connect using Gradle this library to my project?
This need not to store external libraries in my git repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a project that is not a simple Java project and is not made for gradle Im afraid  you have to download the source convert an eclipse adt project manually/automatically to gradle:

1. You cann import it as a module through Android Studio (New-> Module -> Import Existing Project) see http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html
2. You could also just write the build files yourself teaching you a little gradle on the way, just look at the [examples](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=YW5kcm9pZC5jb218dG9vbHN8Z3g6M2U0NDQ2YWFkYWVmNGY5NA) and [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) how to do it

Answer (score 0):

This project doesn't use `gradle` but uses `maven` so dependency to this project can also be handled. You just need to find repository with public access where this project is deployed and add appropriate address in `repositories` section in `build.gradle` file. If there's no such repository You can download the project and install it in the local repository - the downside is that no other developer that works with your project can download this dependency until You make Your repo public.

Furthermore the fact that some project doesn't use `gradle` or `maven` doesn't mean that dependency to this project can't be handled with `gradle`. If this project has fixed versioning scheme and is accessible over the net `gradle` can be configured to use such dependency. Gradle can deal with multiple types of repositories (e.g. flat files).